# BarLegend hiding other legend items

Tags: plotting, legending

Consider the following plot where some individual curves have been given inline legends via `Legended`. A `BarLegend` is also added via `PlotLegends`. The problem is that the `BarLegend` hides some of the other legended items. How to place the `BarLegend` appropriately?

Incorrect plot hiding curve legends

[image]

Expected additional legends:
[image]

```
rf = Function[{f, x}, f Sin[2 x] + 2 Cos[x] Sqrt[f (1 - f Cos[x]^2)]];

fMax[\[Theta]_] = 
 Piecewise[{{1/(    2 - 2 Sin[\[Theta]]), -(\[Pi]/2) < \[Theta] <= \[Pi]/
     6}, {1, \[Pi]/6 <= \[Theta] <= \[Pi]/2}}, 0];

thetaOpt[f_] = ArcTan[Sqrt[f]];

With[{n = 50},
 Show[{
   Plot[
    {
     Evaluate[
      MapAt[Legended[#, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(f = 1\)]\)"] &, 
       Table[Tooltip[rf[f, x], f], {f, 0, 1, 1/n}], -1]],
     Style[
      Legended[rf[fMax[x], x], 
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(max\)]]\)"], 
      Black, Dashed]
     },
    {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2},
    Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10] \[Pi]/8, Automatic},
    PlotStyle -> Hue /@ Range[1, 0, -1/n],

    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 1}}, LegendLabel -> "f"]
    ],
   Plot[
    Legended[rf[Tan[x]^2, x], 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \
\(optimum\)]]\)"],
    {x, 0, \[Pi]/2},
    PlotStyle -> {{Gray, Dashed}}
    ]

   },
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Theta]", "R/H"}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two plots and combine them using `Show`:

```
n = 50;
plots1 = Plot[Evaluate @ Table[Tooltip[rf[f, x], f], {f, 0, 1, 1/n}], 
  {x, -π/2, π/2}, PlotStyle -> Hue /@ Range[1, 0, -1/n], 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 1}}, LegendLabel -> "f"], 
   AxesLabel -> {"θ", "R/H"}, Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10] π/8, Automatic}];

plots2 = Plot[{Tooltip[rf[1, x], 1], rf[fMax[x], x], 
    ConditionalExpression[rf[Tan[x]^2, x], x >= 0]}, {x, -π/2, π/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Directive[ Black, Dashed], {Gray, Dashed}}, 
   PlotLegends -> (Subscript[R, #] & /@ 
    {Row[{f, 1}, "="], Subscript[f, max], Subscript[θ, optimum]})];

Show[plots1, plots2]
```

[image]

Comment: thnx...works!....kind of a hack ;-)..no better way?

Comment: @lineage, updated with  an alternative (cleaner) method.